Facebook doesen't show image even if og:image is present and working
I debug a shared webpage link in facebook debugger and I get a 200 code as result.
The Facebook Debugger can't show the image attached and also it doesen't show while sharing the URL. On Whatsapp and Telegram it works fine.
The og:image is present and the image url is working properly.
The debugger gives me the warning that I have not a fb:app_id but I don't have a Facebook app, also other links on my site work fine but I could not identify the difference.
My website is Wordpress based, I use Yoast SEO for the social tags and use LSCache system.
What can I do?
The debugger link is this:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.balenaludens.it%2F2024%2Friviste-plato-n-169%2F&locale=it_IT

That normally happens when the algorithm blocks the image for a nudity detector or other criteria. If Facebook doesn't like the image you are posting, try uploading another image and see what happens.

@MarcelloPerri I don't think that's the issue, it's a normal image of a magazine:
https://www.balenaludens.it/wp-content/uploads/2024/10/platointestazione169.jpg

I always have problem like your situation exactly, but with telegram. In my researches and so many tries in several ways, I found that the problem is your image quality and size.
It should be a small image with a standard quality to show the preview.
If you have all og tags in your head tag, try to set ideal description with a standard medium, acceptable quality with a good size image as your thumbnail.
After updating, make sure that your target platform like Facebook, doesn't cached your url.
